# How fit my data to a logistic function?

Tags: fitting

I have these two data sets:

```
set1={-9.21034037198, -6.90775527898, -4.60517018599, -2.30258509299, 0.,     2.30258509299, 4.60517018599, 6.90775527898, 9.21034037198}
```

and

```
set2= {0.50000, 0.50000, 0.49970, 0.48471, 0.43806, 0.41499, 0.40731,
0.40486, 0.40409}
```

when I plot these two versus each other I get

[image]
which is similar to a logistic function which has the following form according Wikipedia
$$
f(x)=\frac{L}{1+e^{-k(x-x_0)}}
$$

where

$x_{0}$: the $x$ value of the sigmoid's midpoint;

$L$: the curve's maximum value;

$k$: the logistic growth rate or steepness of the curve

So I think of how I can obtain the appropriate logistic function for my data. I tried this (I added a minus sign behind of x because my data has an inverse direction vs logistic function)

```
FindFit[set2, a/(1 + Exp[-k (-(x - b))]), {a, k, b}, x, Method -> NMinimize]
```

but it doesn't return the correct answers and this is what I see
[image]

when I plot it vs my initial data using

```
Show[{Plot[
   Evaluate[
    a/(1 + Exp[-k (-(x + 1))]) /. {a -> 2.013143006391261`, 
      k -> 0.04418467971781149`, b -> -23.236571721687802`}], {x, 0, 
    8}, PlotStyle -> Red], ListLinePlot[set2]}]
```

So how should I obtain the values for `a`, `b` and `k`? Is it possible I'm wrong about choosing logistic function for fitting?
Also I asked [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4104909/how-to-determine-the-domain-of-a-logistic-function/4105118?noredirect=1#comment8487100_4105118) in Mathematics SE yesterday, but I didn't get answer.

Comment: You probably want to fit a sigmoid function that has a lower and upper bound other than 0 and 1, respectively.  Consider the following:  `f[t_, lower_, upper_, b_] := lower + (upper - lower)/(1 + Exp[-b t])`.

Comment: Your data should be `Transpose@{set1,set2}` in FindFit

Comment: @JimB Thanks a lot, yes I exactly want to limit the domain of the function to 0.4 to 0.5 as you can see in set2. How I apply this to sigmoid function? I tried your suggestion for find fit but it doesn't work. Can you show me how?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci why? I though I must fit my y-axe to a function?

Comment: @Wisdom you have to tell it what x values correspond to the y values. Otherwise Mathematica just assumes the x values are successive integers.

Comment: @b3m2a1 You're right, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should group your data.

```
data = Transpose[{set1, set2}]
```

With a slightly modified model Mathematica evaluates

```
mod =NonlinearModelFit[
data, { a/(1 + Exp[-k ( x - b) ]) + c}, {a, k, b, c}, x,Method -> NMinimize]
Show[{Plot[mod[x], {x, -10, 10}], ListPlot[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain about parameter `c` which you added? One of my friends said you should change the domain and range of the original function to get desire result, I didn't his mean. Did you do so?

Comment: @Wisdom Your approach(assuming `k>0`)  tends  to   `f[x->-Infinity]->L` and `f[x->+Infinity]->0`, that's why your data can't be approximated over the complete range.

Comment: You're right, many thanks

Comment: Thank you @UlrichNeumann. Wonderful!