# How to fit my data to error function?

Tags: fitting

I asked [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244767/how-fit-my-data-to-a-logistic-function) yesterday about fitting my data to logistic function and I received the right answer, but now I have to fit my data

```
set1={-9.21034037198, -6.90775527898, -4.60517018599, -2.30258509299, 0., 2.30258509299, 4.60517018599, 6.90775527898, 9.21034037198}
set2= {0.50000, 0.50000, 0.49970, 0.48471, 0.43806, 0.41499, 0.40731, 0.40486, 0.40409}
```

to the error function which is in sigmoid functions family again, but I don't know how to do so? I tried this

```
mod3 = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, {(2*a)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]*Integrate[-b*Exp[-d*t^2], {t, 0, x}] - 
    c}, {a, b, c, d}, x, Method -> NMinimize]
Show[{Plot[{(2*a)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]*Integrate[-b*Exp[-d*t^2], {t, 0, x}] - 
     c}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}], ListPlot[data]}]
```

but it doesn't work! We know the value of function tends to 1 for x goes to infinity and -1 for x goes to -infinity. In previous question the problem was solved by adding a `c` constantm but in this case what is the problem?

Should I use `Erf` built-in function instead of the explicit form of error function which I have used above?

Comment: The size of the data equals 8. This is too little for a relaible fit.

Comment: But it worked for logistic function in previous question

Comment: A working code not necessarily produces a reliable result. The claim "fits fine" is empty words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model with summarized coefficient `aa:= a b/Sqrt[d]` gives

```
data=Transpose[{set1,set2}]
mod3 = NonlinearModelFit[
Transpose[{set1,set2}], {-c - aa  Erf[Sqrt[d] x], d > 0 }, {aa, c, d}, x,Method -> NMinimize]
Show[{Plot[mod3[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}],ListPlot[data]}]
```

[image]

fits fine.

Comment: Dear Ulrich please add explanation about the summerized coefficient to your answer.  Why you write so? And what is the general way to fit days to a function? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Wisdom I took this form because `NonlinearModelFit` couldn't handle the general form. From the result `mod3["BestFitParameters"] (*{aa -> 0.0477129, c -> -0.450413, d -> 0.114372}*)` it follows (see my first formula)  `a b==Sqrt[d] aa  /. mod3["BestFitParameters"]`

Comment: So we don't have the values of `a` and `b` individually? so what is the benefit of writing `aa` as a summarized coefficient? sorry for more question but I want to understand the logic of your solutions for any fitting.

Comment: As you can see the solution concerning the product `a b` isn't  unique. Perhaps that's the reason why `NonlinearModelFit` fails

Comment: OK thanks and How you found that you should add `sqrt[d]` (not `d`) in the original formula?

Comment: I took the formula from your model.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extended comment.

When using @UlrichNeumann 's model you might be interested in estimating the values of the upper and lower limits (along with some measure of precision).  You can do that in a variety of ways but maybe the simplest is by reparameterizing the model to include the upper and lower limits explicitly.  That transformation is found by making the following substitution:

```
{aa -> 1/2 (-lower + upper), c -> 1/2 (-lower - upper)}
```

So the model becomes:

```
model = (lower + upper)/2 - Erf[Sqrt[d] x] (upper - lower)/2;
```

And the fit process is

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{set1, set2}], {model, d > 0}, {lower, upper, d}, x, 
  Method -> NMinimize];
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table]

```
Show[{Plot[nlm[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], PlotRangeClipping -> False],
  ListPlot[data]}]
```

[image: Plot of data and fit]

Comment: Thanks, what are the benefits of this task?

Comment: When performing a regression there are typically (but not exclusively) 3 types of objective:  (1) Make predictions where you don't have data, (2) interpret coefficients, and (3) Calculate functions of parameters.  Your question currently just states you want a "fit".  The other answer gives you item (1).  In my answer I was just attempting to show you how you could obtain items (2) and (3).

Comment: Thanks for your good explanation, yes my objective was the item 1, but your answer was useful for better understanding.